# How to load font-awesome icons in rails view?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

This could be a dumb question but I am not able to figure it out How to use font-awesome icons in `rails` view.

I had a `static` standalone html (added into rails view) and here is the code:

```
<span class="icon-white">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/xyz">
     <i class="icon icon-twitter"></i>
  </a>
</span>
```

I had also included

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "icons.min.css" %>
```

in same view. What I am missing here? How can I add into rails view.

Comment: inspect the page to see if the css is being loaded or not.. if yes try to check where its loaded..

Comment: I can see the `icon.min.css` is loading into page

Answer (score 0):

Use this

> gem "font-awesome-rails"

In your application.css add these lines:

```
/*
 *= require font-awesome
 */
```

and If you prefer SCSS, add these lines in your application.css.scss file (don't forget to delete *application.css* file if you are using SCSS) :

```
@import "font-awesome";
```

If you use the Sass indented syntax, add this to your application.css.sass file:

```
@import font-awesome
```

Comment: Actually I did that. Install gem -> added to my gem file -> bundle install -> added to my `application.css`. Do I need to make changes in `html.erb` file as well?

Comment: If you are using gem then you need not to mention it in `html.erb`.

Comment: That means this class supposed to work ? <i class="icon icon-twitter"></i>

Comment: Font awesome classes use the prefix fa fa-*, not icon icon-^. See [twitter icon](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/twitter/).